# Git Moving Files into Folders

Tags: git, github

I am quite new to git and version control in general, and have question about moving files around. I have a master repo on GitHub, with 6 source files.

I've done a lot of work on the project and now my local branch contains two folders with the sources in those.

The directory structure used to be like:

Master:

- File 1
- File 2
- File 3
- File 4
- File 5
- File 6

Where as my local branch now looks like this:

New Folder 1:

- New File 1
- New File 2
- New File 3

New Folder 2:

- File 1
- File 2
- File 3
- File 4
- File 5
- File 6

How can I move my local structure to the master branch without losing my commit history on the old files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just commit. Git blame etc will generally do a pretty good job of automatically detecting moves.

Answer (score 9):

git doesn't actually track "moves" of files, it infers it on demand from similar content.  So, just make the move and add / remove files as appropriate.  (You will make life easier for the tools in future if you avoid making changes to the content as well as moving them in a single commit.)

Then, to see the log accounting for moves, use `-M`, `-C`, or their variants to `git log`.  Similar flags apply to other tools, and you should read the help to understand the detail of what they do.

If you use `git mv` on a file, it just does the `git rm` and `git add` for you.

Comment: others explane it to difficult the mv does all you need. Create the folder to mv to first for convenience

Answer (score 5):

The other posters are correct, however if you want to confirm that git is going to see these as moves (and not a combination of delete/create), run a `git status`.  You should see:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    oldfile.txt -> newFolder/newfile.txt
```

Comment: If git does see the move as a combination of delete/create, what to do then?

Comment: Stage removing files from previous folder, then stage adding files in new folder - most probably git see this as renaming.

Answer (score 2):

In github, if you don't have too many files to move, an interesting alternative is to Edit the file, and change it's name to:

```
folder_to_move_into/file_name
```

When you commit, the file is moved to the folder. If the folder doesn't exist, it will be created.